# Use multi core to speed up building os.osx.x86 webpack?

Tags: node.js, meteor, webpack

Since installing webpack my build times are much longer when working on API changes. I also notice that every time meteor builds it only uses 1 of my cpu cores. I've done a little research and come across this package https://www.npmjs.com/package/parallel-transpile2 but I'm not sure how to integrate into my app. I'm using 
[meteor add webpack:webpack](https://github.com/thereactivestack/meteor-webpack/tree/master/packages/webpack/) and webpack:react.

[Edit] Sean's response for parallel-webpack doesn't provide an example with [atmosophere's webpack:webpack](https://github.com/thereactivestack/meteor-webpack/tree/master/packages/webpack/) package - no webpack.config.js, a webpack.json instead

If someone has done this already I'd appreciate your aid, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Meteor 1.4 update made dramatic improvements to server side build speed which was the issue I was trying to resolve with multi-core support for webpack.

Per this **closed** issued: https://github.com/thereactivestack/meteor-webpack/issues/265 , neither the package author or myself are pursuing this feature further.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using parallel transpile, I would recommend the parallel-webpack tool. It will run in parallel multiple webpack configs when passed as an array.

https://github.com/trivago/parallel-webpack/blob/master/README.md#basic-example

```
module.exports = [{
    entry: 'pageA.js',
    output: {
        path: './dist',
        filename: 'pageA.bundle.js'
    }
}, {
    entry: 'pageB.js',
    output: {
        path: './dist',
        filename: 'pageB.bundle.js'
    }
}];
```

Comment: I suppose my question is two parts. This definitely seems like an important part of the answer, but my question would now be - how to do it with the [atmosophere webpack:webpack](https://github.com/thereactivestack/meteor-webpack/tree/master/packages/webpack/) package - no webpack.config.js, a webpack.json instead